# SQL - Window Count with reset

Tags: sql, function, count, hana

I am using SQL and trying to achieve the following results (running_count).

I tried out window function counting, but I do not know how to achieve the reseting of my counter.

```
select *,
     count(1) over 
(partition by ID, DATE order by DATE rows unbounded preceding) -1 as "run_count"  from table
```

My (resulttable) should look like this. The count should reset between days, but **also** when a B occurs in between A.

| ID | Date | Flag | Running_Count |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10/10 | A | 1 |  |
| **2** | **10/10** | **B** | **0** | -> reset |
| **3** | **10/10** | **B** | **0** | -> reset |
| 4 | 10/10 | A | 1 |  |
| 5 | 10/10 | A | 2 |  |
| 6 | 10/10 | A | 3 |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 11/10 | B | 0 |  |
| 2 | 11/10 | B | 0 |  |
| 3 | 11/10 | A | 1 |  |
| 4 | 11/10 | A | 2 |  |
| 5 | 11/10 | A | 3 |  |
| 6 | 11/10 | A | 4 |  |
| **7** | **11/10** | **B** | **0** | -> reset |
| 8 | 11/10 | A | 1 |  |

Comment: Please explain the logic for your count and tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: i have done that. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to count "A"s separated by "B"s, starting over on each day.

If so, you can define the group as the number of "B"s before each value and then do some calculations:

```
select t.*,
       (case when flag = 'A' then row_number() over (partition by date, grp, flag order by id)
             else 0
        end) as running_count
from (select t.*, sum(case when flag = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by date order by id) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://rextester.com/UERP91339) is a rextester (which uses Postgres).

Comment: hi. thanks, but you are not 100% right. Yes, i want to count the A's and B's separted by each day, but **also** when a B is between A.

Comment: @user3733265 . . . That is what this does.

Comment: @user3733265 . . . I see that.  `flag` is needed in the `partition by` clause.  I added a rextester.  It is for Postgres but it should work exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following SQLScript select statement

It is possible that it might be solved easier. I used subselects to display the solution step by step.

Inner most SELECT checks if there is a change from another value to 'A' using [SQL Lag() function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/lag-function-in-sql-server-2012-for-previous-values.aspx)

The following SubSelect performs a [SQL running-sum](http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/stock-aging-using-sqlscript-on-sap-hana-database.aspx) solution using SUM() aggregate function with unbounded preceding option

The outer-most SELECT uses Row_Number() function to create the desired count value.

```
select
    id,
    date,
    flag,
    case when flag = 'A' then
    row_number() over (partition by date, groupid order by id) 
    else 0
    end as rn
from (
    select
        id,
        date,
        flag,
        sum(is_change) over (partition by date order by id rows unbounded preceding) groupid -- running sum
    from (
        select
            id,
            date,
            flag,
            case 
                when 
                    flag = 'A' and 
                    (
                        (lag(flag, 1) over (partition by date order by id)) is null or
                        (lag(flag, 1) over (partition by date order by id)) = 'B'
                    ) -- check prev
                then 1
                else 0
            end as is_change
        from TblTest
    ) tbl
) t
order by date, id
```

I hope it is useful and can be used in your development

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can define grouping based on number of B flag occurences and then use Row_number to number rows for each group:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    date,
    flag,
    CASE WHEN flag = 'B' THEN 0 ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date, B_COUNT ORDER BY ID) END AS "RUNNING_COUNT"
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            TA.ID,
            TA.date,
            TA.flag,
            CASE WHEN SUM(TB.COUNT) IS NULL AND flag = 'A' THEN 0 ELSE SUM(TB.COUNT) END AS B_COUNT
        FROM
            table TA
            LEFT JOIN 
                        (
                            SELECT
                                ID, date, 1 AS "COUNT"
                            FROM
                                table
                            WHERE 
                                flag = 'B'                  
                        )   TB ON TA.date = TB.date AND TA.ID > TB.ID AND TA.flag = 'A'
        GROUP BY
            TA.ID,
            TA.date,
            TA.flag
    )
ORDER BY 
    date, ID, flag;
```

It will give you expected result.